# Running a PHPUnit Test yields "Class Not Found" Error

Tags: php, zend-framework, tdd, phpunit, autoloader

This is a question on PHP Unit Test giving me a Class Not Found Error.

**Background**

I am using Zend Studio 10.5 to develop a Zend Framework 2 application.  I have a few modules loaded, including `ZfcUser` and `BjyAuthorize`

FedcoUser is the module that has a Controller Guard that uses guard rules of BjyAuthorize:

```
<?php
namespace FedcoUser\Controller;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use ZfcUser\Controller\UserController as ZfcUserController;

class MachinistController extends ZfcUserController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!$this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute($this->getOptions()->getLoginRedirectRoute());
        }

        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Using Zend Studio 10.5 native menus, I have created a test case for the controller above.  When I run it I get the following error:

```
Debug Error: FedcoUser/Controller/MachinistController.php line 8 - Class 'ZfcUser\Controller\UserController' not found
```

My assumption is that somehow, autoloader for PHPUnit cannot figure out where the class is being placed, because the class it cannot find is located at

```
vendor/zf-commons/zfc-user/src/ZfcUser/Controller/UserController.php
```

I am not yet familiar with how PHPUnit works to be able to fix this error.  Does PHPUnit even have an autoloader?  There are files called `bootstrap.php`, `phpunit.xml`, and `TestConfiguration.php` in my module's `/test/` folder, if that helps.  I tried to randomly add various modules and paths to `TestConfiguration.php` file as below but it did not help:

```
 $additionalModulePaths = array(
     'ZfcUser' => realpath('vendor/zf-commons/zfc-user/src/ZfcUser/Controller/UserController.php'),
);
```

Can you help?

Comment: Who are you using autoloading in your project?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  An answer I give may not be relevant.  I am using ZendSkeletonApplication + several Zfc modules + BjyAuthorize module.  I have added a FedcoUser module that has Module.php with getAutoloaderConfig() function.  there are also autoload_classmap.php, autoload_function.php, and autoload_register.php files.  I can post the code inside of them if it is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up loading additional namespaces into my config inside my TestConfiguration.php file:

```php
$additionalNamespaces = array(
    'ZfcUser\Controller' => __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/zf-commons/zfc-user/src/ZfcUser/Controller/'
);
```

that fit in nicely into my `bootstrap.php`, which had the following code:

```
// setup autoloader
AutoloaderFactory::factory(
    array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            StandardAutoloader::AUTOREGISTER_ZF => true,
            StandardAutoloader::ACT_AS_FALLBACK => false,
            StandardAutoloader::LOAD_NS => $additionalNamespaces,
        )
    )
);
```